# Left-pads the number with ` -` instead of spaces and 0

Tags: c, printf

When we use `printf`  we can write this :

```
int i = 1;
printf("%06d" i);
```

Then I got `000001`, the `0` fill the space

So is there a way a I can use other character like `-` to fill the space instead of `0`?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4133356/2235132) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look like that is an option with functions of the `printf` family: your choices there are zeros `'0'` or spaces `' '`. If you must pad with another character, you need to perform the conversion yourself.

One way of doing this would be using `sprintf` to print into a 6-character buffer with space padding, then replacing spaces with dashes `'-'`, like this:

```
char buf[12]; // 11 for the number plus one for the terminator
sprintf(buf, "%6d", i);
char *p = buf;
while (*p == ' ') {
    *p++ = '-';
}
printf("%s", buf);
```

Comment: Thanks , I just want to know  whether there is a short way or not . :)

Comment: `buf[7]` should be larger as `%6d` does not limit the number of characters printed, only specifies the minimum.

Comment: I am in the middle of dealing with the question of best size in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708679/how-to-improve-buffer-size-determination-for-printfing-various-integer-types